# How do I bind a composite component in JSF?

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I have a composite component which is composed of other composite components. Now I would like to render only some of the child components within the parent component. From the Java EE tutorial I take it that I should probably bind my child components to some property of the backing bean for my parent component so that I can access their `render` attribute.

However, the NetBeans IDE does not know about a `binding` attribute for my composite components. So how am I supposed to do this?

Use case: The parent component is some wizard which should display only one of the child components at a time. Think of it as a poor man's tabbed view. I know there are libraries which provide ready-made components for this, but I do not want to add another dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netbeans is lying. That attribute is definitely supported on [`<ui:component>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/component.html). Just use it and ignore the warning/error in the IDE. Or better, just use the `rendered` attribute; the need to conditionally render components is not a valid reason to prefer `binding` over `rendered`.

Comment: Yes, NetBeans is lying, but also the Java EE tutorial 7 says that the `binding` attribute would be present for output tags, and my composite component is a `UINamingContainer`, not a `UIOutput`.

Comment: No, it's present on [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html), which is also represented by `<ui:component>` (have you clicked the VDL link in my answer?).

Comment: Thanks, I did, but I am using a custom component, that is the `interface` and `implementation` tags of the `http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite` namespace. Don't know how this relates to your tag.

Comment: I know. Composite components are implicitly interpreted as `<ui:component>`. The "custom component" is by the way the wrong term for composite components. See further also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269 and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info